# bootstrap 4 dynamic nav not showing pane

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, navbar, tampermonkey

I am creating a dynamic list group with javascript behaviour for something that can change on every page refresh. I have been using the instructions here:

[List group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/)

Unfortunately i cant gt the pane on the right to work but i can get the columns on the left to highlight and change. I am using Tampermonkey to implement this and doing it on the fly.

I was getting an error relating to jquery $ which may have been a conflict and seems to be resolved.

I can create the divs and all all the information to them so i see them in my dev tools, all there perfect.

[image: Pane divs]

[image: Nav bar divs]

I am dynamically adding the CDN to the page as i have no control over it other than tampermonkey. This may be where the trouble is.

[image: Head Tags]

```
    var resources5 = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var bootstrapCSS2 = document.createElement('link');
          bootstrapCSS2.rel = 'stylesheet';
                                                                  bootstrapCSS2.href += 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'; //https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css';//top
         bootstrapCSS2.integrity += 'sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO';
         bootstrapCSS2.crossOrigin += 'anonymous';


resources5.appendChild(bootstrapCSS2);
```

And heres where i append it to the page:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(
    function() {
      document.body.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]);

         document.head.appendChild(resources5);
```

This is the start of my Tampermonkey script:
(//@ at the start of these)

```
grant       none
require     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
include     https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
include     https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
include     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js
include     https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==
```

I know this is something silly and dont think its related to making the divs. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I think im tripping up on where the list-group links up with the tab content. Im adding tabs and tab content dynamically.

Comment: So ive added slim.min.js (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js) and im now getting an error: TypeError: jQuery.fx is undefined

Comment: Ok i have it working now with a mixture of lists and divs. The only problem now is the li tags show outside the column div. Is this a known problem?

Comment: Fixed it, just had to set width to 100%